# Screen refresh/display problem in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: xubuntu, screen

I have just installed Xubuntu 14.04 as a dual boot on a desk top (Pentium R 4 CPU, 2.66 GHZ, 2G RAM) running XP home edition. In some situations when in Xubuntu I am having what seem to be screen refresh problems.

1. When I open File Manager or Settings Manager the text names of various apps display but most of the icons do not. Moving the mouse over an app name generally causes the icon to appear, but it often vanishes once the mouse pointer is moved. This issue occurs irrespective of the view setting.

Icons appear fine in the menu that comes up when I right click in the desktop, and in the menu that comes up when I click the mouse icon at top left.

1. What I suspect is a related issue. In Abiword text sometimes fades, disappears or does not display immediately when I type, or text of the whole document fades. It then comes back or darkens if I left click a few times on the text. If I scroll through a document the text often fades and may remain faded until I left click a few times.

Answer (score 1):

I went to **Settings > Appearance > Fonts > Rendering**

changed **Sub-pixel order** to: **None**

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: Where the hell the same setting in ubuntu 14.10...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe was the share memory with video ram. Take a look in the /etc/X11/xorg.conf (in 16.04 is a directory /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/). In "Section 'Device'" search for "VideoRam" and change the number for a correctly information of your shared ram with your video onboard.

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Generic Video Card"
    VendorName  "Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]"
        BoardName   "771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter"
    Busid "PCI:1:0:0"
    Driver "vesa"
    Screen 0
        Option "UseFBDev" "true"
        Option "DPMS"
        Option "ShadowFB"
        Option "MaxXFBMem"
        VideoRam 128000
        Option "RenderAccel" "true"
        Option "AllowGLXWithComposite" "true"
        Option "backingstore" "true"
        Option "AddARGBGLXVisuals" "True"
```

If "VideoRam" not to exist, try to create.